# Software to export firefox addons

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I'd like a program which could zip up all of my addons in firefox so i can just move it to a new computer and walah install the same extensions/addons with one click. i know this is already developed because i've used it before however i can't remember the name to it.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Just zip your user profile and move it around, you'll keep ALL your settings, not just your add-ons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [CLEO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2942/) and [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109/).

> FEBE (**Firefox Environment Backup Extension**) allows you to quickly and easily backup your Firefox extensions. In fact, it goes beyond just backing up -- It will actually rebuild your extensions individually into installable .xpi files. Now you can easily synchronize your office and home browsers.
>
> CLEO (**Compact Library Extension Organizer**) is a Firefox extension that works with FEBE to package any number of extensions/themes into a single, installable .xpi file.

<sup>also, OPIE (**[Ordered Preference Import/Export](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6152/)**) is a Firefox extension that allows you to import and export your installed extension preferences. This is useful when installing extensions in a new profile, or synchronizing multiple Firefox installations.</sup>

---

I also keep my profile backed up for recovery and to start using it on a new machine.

Comment: +agreed... FEBE is great.

Comment: None of these extensions appear to be available on AMO any more -- they were probably obsoleted by the transition to WebExtensions.

Answer (score 5):

I used CLEO and FEBE until I found [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/). Is far easier to use and allows you to backup and restore bookmarks, mail, contacts, history, extensions, passwords, etc.

[image: MozBackup components selection]

Comment: Awesome. If only it worked in Linux...

Answer (score 1):

nik's answer referencing FEBE is probably what you're looking for.  Just wanted to point out that mozilla also provides the ['addon collector'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/) extension that allows you to subscribe to extension collections.  If you also install the ['massive extender'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/89648/) extension, you can install all your add-ons in one batch.

Comment: Note that Add-on Collector is not (yet?) compatible with Firefox 4 as of Beta 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you are living in 2014 and still using Firefox, use [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync). It's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an Add-On collection on Mozilla's [web site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/), and list all your favorite extensions there. Also, you can use the [add-on collector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/collector) to subscribe to others collections..

Answer (score 0):

At the moment(2019) all installed extensions/addons are stored in its installation format (.xpi)  in the profile folder. (...Profiles\xxxxxxx.default\extensions)

So you can zip all the xpi together.

By the way, this method is common either for FF Quantum and its new webextensions(above ver. 57) and Firefox using XUL extensions (below ver. 57)

Note some files can have obfuscated names such as {b9db16a4-6edc-47ec-a1f4-b86292ed211d}.xpi

Using about:support
you can find the name associated to this addon